# How is the Huygens-Fresnel principle of diffraction modified when light is confined to a planar dielectric waveguide?

Tags: optics, diffraction

The Huygens-Fresnel principle essentially states that in order to propagate an electromagnetic wavefront in free-space, one must superimpose the so-called "secondary wavelets", which are spherical waves emanating from every point of the current wavefront. I have searched for a modified version of this principle when light is confined to a dielectric planar waveguide, but my efforts have been fruitless. There is a clear intuition that a beam confined to a planar waveguide must expand laterally, as for example a Gaussian beam does in free-space, however due to the beam's vertical confinement, this expansion should only take place along one axis instead of two. Is anyone aware of a somewhat formal treatment of this in terms of diffraction theory?

Comment: The usual formulation of the Huygens-Fresnel principle is in a scalar form. Once you confine the EM wave into a waveguide, be it dielectric or metallic, you must employ the principle to each rectangular component separately and then enforce between them the various boundary conditions, e.g., $E_{||}$ be $0$ on a metal or be continuous across a dielectric jump, etc. I have never seen this done or even imagine how could be done in practice.